# Elastic beanstalk postinstall errors when using webpack

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my fluxible node.js app to elastic beanstalk and I'm getting a permission error when I try to run the postinstall step.  Is there a configuration I should be setting on elastic beanstalk?

```
"postInstall":  "node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.production.js",
```

Error

```
 Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/deployment/application/node_modules/unicode/category/Cc.js'
      at Error (native)

  npm ERR! Linux 4.9.27-14.31.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.10.0-linux-x64/bin/npm" "--production" "rebuild"
  npm ERR! node v6.10.0
  npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! unicode@0.6.1 postinstall: `node install.js`
```

Comment: Can you show any of the webpack config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk has an incompatibility with the unicode node module.

This is the workaround that AWS support gave me that works using ebextensions.

`.ebextensions/unicode.config`

```
packages:
  yum:
    unicode-ucd: []

commands:
  symlink_unicode:
    command: "ln -fs /usr/share/unicode/ucd/UnicodeData.txt /usr/share/unicode/UnicodeData.txt"
```